# Gnuplot dot dash

Tags: gnuplot

Hi guys I'm using Windows and I'm trying to get something done in Gnuplot. I need to set the line style of my graph as dot dash.

http://sparky.rice.edu/gnuplot.html tells me that:

```
 Differs from x11 to postscript
 lt chooses a particular line type: -1=black 1=red 2=grn 3=blue 4=purple 5=aqua 6=brn 7=orange 8=light-brn
 lt must be specified before pt for colored points
 for postscipt -1=normal, 1=grey, 2=dashed, 3=hashed, 4=dot, 5=dot-dash
```

What does he mean by postscript here? How can I achieve this? I've been trying many times to plot my graph using the command:
plot 'graph1.txt' with lines lt 5 but I don't get the dot-dash line.

Help would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This means that the values given for `lt` only work when you are plotting to a Postscript file, and will not work if you plot in a window in the straightforward way. Simplest thing would be to plot to a Postscript file using

```
set term postscript
set output "file.ps"
```

The plot will be in `file.ps`.

Comment: i see. but i need to export it as .eps. So how do i go about converting .ps to .eps? I'd like to reiterate that I'm using Windows. thank you!